# How to Add multivalue Data in Solr.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, solrnet, solr

I want to Add product with Solr.net Schema file. my database Table is

```
Category table - catid, catname
Brand table - brandid, brandname
Item table - productid, productname, productdesc
Filter table- key, value
```

Note:- if i add all with a Table then data Repeatation occur. so if u have better solution then please suggest me with an examle.

Thanks in Advance. Ashutosh 9818842034

Comment: I believe Mauricio's answer below answers your question - you should accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

To represent a multiValued field in Solr/SolrNet, first you have to declare the field as [multiValued in the Solr schema](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Common_field_options). Then [map the field as a property of collection type](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Mapping).

You mention "data repetition". That is expected in Solr, as you have to denormalize your data. See the [Solr schema design wiki for reference](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaDesign).

Answer (score 1):

To index products in Solr the fields in your schema.xml should be something like this:

```
<fields>
  <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
  <field name="name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="desc" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="catname" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
  <field name="brandname" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
</fields>
```

Notice `multiValued="true"` is set for the category name, so products can have more than one category. I don't think you need to send to Solr category Ids or brand Ids, but that depends on your application.